# compass-rails gem not being run in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, compass-sass

My gemfile recently upgraded my compass-rails gem. I started getting the following error (production on heroku only - works fine locally), and have been stuck on it for hours:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14284ms
2012-09-03T20:53:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-03T20:53:25+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
2012-09-03T20:53:25+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

I think part of the problem must lie within the fact the /app/app/ is appearing in the path here - but I dont understand why. When I change the compass config below, to "assets/stylesheets" I still see /app/app/ in the trace error.

production.rb:

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false
```

compass.rb

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
project_type = :rails
sass_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets"
```

Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.4'
  gem 'yui-compressor', '0.9.6'
  gem 'compass-rails'
end
```

In my application.css.scss file:

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

I've been trying every solution I can find without any luck so far

Anything sticking out?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, moving compass-rails out of :assets works but is not an ideal solution.

Checking through the output from the push to heroku I found

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
```

But it is compiling locally with

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

The solution is not to instantiate the DB when precompiling assets. In config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

See this issue in the compass-rails project:

https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/19

Comment: The reason that moving compass-rails out of :assets works is because Heroku is trying to compile the stylesheet on the fly because `rake assets:precompile` failed. However, it's definitely only a workaround solution - Rimian's solution makes the precompile work, and compass-rails should definitely remain in the :assets group.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my rails to 3.2+ and ended up moving compass-rails outside of the assets group to make it work. I dont really understand why it works, but it seemed to do the trick.